# /bin/bash: --pkg: command not found

Tags: compiling, jhbuild

I am attempting to build a package using `jhbuild` but am running into an error during the build phase. The output for this phase is:

```
*** Building egg-list-box *** [1/1]
make -j 8
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/devel/git.gnome.org/egg-list-box'
  CC     test-sel.o
  CC     test-flow-box.o
  VALAC  test_list_vala.stamp
/bin/bash: --pkg: command not found
  VALAC  test_scrolled_vala.stamp
/bin/bash: --pkg: command not found
make[1]: *** [test_list_vala.stamp] Error 127
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [test_scrolled_vala.stamp] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/devel/git.gnome.org/egg-list-box'
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Error during phase build of egg-list-box: ########## Error running make -j 8 *** [1/1]
```

The specific error message is

```
/bin/bash: --pkg: command not found
```

I'm pretty sure it's because I am missing the right package, but I don't know what one I should be installing. Every time I try to search the package directory for `pkg` I always end up with hist for `dpkg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that this was a Vala app and a special set of build tools had to be installed for the build to succeed. Full details about building Vala apps on Ubuntu can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vala), but the important bit, installing the Vala compiler, is

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 7DAAC99C
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install valac-0.18 vala-0.18-doc valac-0.18-dbg
```